# How can I fix this error that I'm getting using the inner_join function?

Tags: r, inner-join

```
vg1<-rev_vg[,c(4,6,11)]

df2006<-vg1%>%
  filter(Year==2006)%>%
  rename(Sales2006=Global_Sales)

View(df2006)

df2016<-vg1%>%
  filter(Year==2016)%>%
  rename(Sales2016=Global_Sales)

View(df2016)

merged_df<-vg1%>%
  inner_join(vg2,by="Publisher")
```

Error: `by` can't contain join column `Publisher` which is missing from RHS

Not really sure how to fix this error to merge these data frames.

P.S. I'm using a data set called "video game sales". Versions of it can be found on Kaggle, although they may not be identical to the set that I am working with.

Comment: You fix the error by specifying the correct names of the variables to join on. Obviously, `Publisher` is not a variable in vg2.

Comment: And note that the commands between the first and the last have absolutely no effect on the last command.

Comment: Please `dput` your data frames, or show the output of `str(vg1)` and `str(vg2)`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is obvious if you read the error, there is no variable called "Publisher" in one of your data frames. The variable in `by` needs to be present in both frames or you can pass two different names using `by = c(x, y)`.

See: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html

---

You say that both `vg1` and `vg2` have the publisher variable, and the same name on that variable but we could do with the output of `str()` on the dataframes to support this. For what it's worth, the following exactly repeats your error

```
library(tidyverse)

vg1 <- data.frame(
  Publisher = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D"), 
  Game = c(1:7))

vg2 <- data.frame(
  Pub = LETTERS[1:4],
  Year = c(2004, 2005, 2007, 2002))

vg1 %>% 
  inner_join(vg2, by = "Publisher")
```

While this works fine

```
library(tidyverse)

vg1 <- data.frame(
  Publisher = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D"), 
  Game = c(1:7))

vg2 <- data.frame(
  Publisher = LETTERS[1:4],
  Year = c(2004, 2005, 2007, 2002))

vg1 %>% 
  inner_join(vg2, by = "Publisher")
```

Note that `vg1 %>% inner_join(vg2, by = c("Publisher" = "Pub"))` would also have worked.

Comment: When I view my data frames, the columns representing the variables show that Publisher is in each one. I suspected that maybe it was because I haven't aggregated my Publishers (e.g. Nintendo would show up 5 times for rows 1-5 in vg1 but not in vg2). I tried to add pictures to my question to show but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: Could you provide code to make your example reproducible,  e.g. post the output of `dput()` for each of your dataframes

Comment: @firefly the code added shows a) that missing variables from one df replicates your error, and b) that it doesn't matter that vg1 has multiple rows for the same publisher.